# Python regular expression to extract strings

Tags: python, regex

Here is my test sentence:

> in setup or operation state, the blood warmer shall declare an urgent state if its liquid leakage sensor detects liquid leakage.

I want extract:

> setup or operation

note that there maybe two or more state in the sentence,Just find the first one as the boundary.

I test my code in regex101:
https://regex101.com/r/p18Hef/1

```
(in (.*) (state|mode|phase|states))
```

but it couldn't find the first state...

Answer (score 3):

Regex is greedy by default. Your `.*` is matching all the way out to the next instance of "state", so you need to mark your `.*` as lazy with a `?`.

The final regex is: `(in (.*?) (state|mode|phase|states))`.

More information can be seen at [Regular expression operations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#index-6).

Comment: Maybe this is what he really wants? `(?<=in ).*?(?=state|mode|phase|states)`